# autoload function vs json object is javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

I was thinking about what is best for my JavaScript code.

I have a HTML page that contains some forms. So I bring life to it with JavaScript here we go.

I was thinking about what the best way to exploit my JavaScript code.

First to create a JSON object that has all attributes and methods I need.

For example

```
var myObject={
    menuBtn: null,
    init: function(){ 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            /* the code will be executed after the load */
        });
    },
    listenToMenuButton: function(){ 
        /* add a listener to the button */
    }
};

myObject.init(); // to start working
```

or instead of that

```
(function($){
    var me = this;
    me.menuBtn = null;
    me.listenToMenuButton = function(){
        /* add a listener to the button */
    };
    me.init=function(){
        /* code to init all elements */
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Can any one advise me what is best and what are the advantages (of the two approaches)?

For example I know that the first implementation allows me to call a method as many times as I want. But the drawback of it is that the user can do some hack on it and call it (from firebug for example) and apply a  behavior that was a fake one/

And when should I develop an extension (jQuery)?

I hope you guys can help me to design well my code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation

Comment: Your second approach does not work (or at least is bug-ridden), so choose the first one.

Comment: lol i think no body have understood what i trying to do  any way thank  u

Answer (score 2):

I understand how you feel. I felt like that for a long time until I found this:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/